# Update select2 with ajax symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, jquery-select2

I made a form that creates new select options and now I want to update that select input type with ajax so I don't have to reload the whole page.

The way I tried is this:

The controller returns this

```
return new JsonResponse(['data'=>$em->getRepository('AppBundle:ClasificacionAO')->findAll()]);
```

and the Ajax is

```
$.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
             // optionally check if the response is what you wanted
             //if (data.response == 'deleted') {
             //
                      $('select').select2({
                            data: data
                        });

            //also tried with the id: paciente_form_clasificacionAO
            //$('paciente_form_clasificacionAO').select2({
            //                                data: data
            //                            });



             //}
         }
        })
```

The select options don't update until I refresh the whole page, how do I fix it to show the new select option created?

Comment: What select2 version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the v4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. The problem was that the controller wasn't passing the array in a valid way. After that it was just to use the data in javascript.

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ClasificacionAO')->findAll();
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $response1[] = array(
                'key' => $entity->getIdentificadorAO(),
                // other fields
            );
            $response2[] = array(
                'value' => $entity->getId(),
                // other fields
            );
        }

        return new JsonResponse(([$response1,$response2]));
```

The Ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {

         dataOptions = data[0];
         dataIds     = data[1];

        // Get the raw DOM object for the select box
        select = document.getElementById('paciente_form_clasificacionAO');

        // Clear the old options
        select.options.length = 0;

        // Load the new options
        // Or whatever source information you're working with
        for (var index = 0; index < dataOptions.length; index++) {
          option = dataOptions[index];
          opt1 = document.createElement("option");
          opt1.text = option['key'];

          opt1.value = dataIds[index]['value'];
           //console.log(opt1);

          select.options.add(opt1);
        }

     }
    })
```